# Best Practices for Strip down Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I strip down Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1807/how-can-i-strip-down-ubuntu)

especially handons

But i like to built a virtual cloud for my labs with minimal resources using ubuntu.

I would like to know after a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

1. What command to total strip down the OS?
2. What step or command to Harden the OS?
3. What command to initial to get the stable HTTP / HTTPS / FTP / DNS server module?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you install [Ubuntu Server edition](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server).

It seems to fit your needs.