# Best way to make Ubuntu installation as lean as possible?

Tags: kernel

My goal is to make my OS lean as much as possible: only basic OS (kernel) and applications I need.

- Kernel, apt, basic bins.
- Network manager.
- Xfce (terminal, file manager).
- Evolution.
- Chromium.

What is the best way to manage packages and all dependencies?

```
apt list --installed
```

or

```
dpkg -l
```

shows me all installed packages. Is there any command to show this list with dependency structure? For example as a tree?

Or when I uninstall application, is possible to show me what could be disturbed?

Or what is the best way to make leanest ubuntu with xfce for example.

I tried to install Ubuntu mini, but I have problem with wifi driver not being detected: see my question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164769/ubuntu-minimal-install-no-wifi-detected). But I think better to learn administrate os then reinstalling.

Comment: I would build from the minimal install you've already mentioned. Okay your wifi wasn't detected, from your installed system you can work out the module that is required to provide it - and add that to the minimal post-install (if you don't have ethernet; add it from thumb-drive and install via `dpkg`)

Comment: There are many questions on the topic here, and you are welcome to search for them. I doubt there is a best way to do it, or to answer such questions. Generally, let APT manage packages and dependencies, avoid DEs like Gnome, KDE,XFCE, etc, also avoid programs with lots of dependencies, such as Gnome Network Manager, Evolution, Chromium.

Comment: @guiverc I tried many things, here is my issue. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1164769/ubuntu-minimal-install-no-wifi-detected . :/ I will try to uninstall package by package, I hope it is the way.

Comment: Once you mention Evolution, you're no longer going to have anywhere near a minimal system!

Comment: I was talking about installing packages, not copying files (you provided little detail in the other question about what you meant by "copy" - if it was `cp` only those files?  I didn't mean that. Rather than copying `/lib/modules/5.3.0-13-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko`  (a file picked at random from a like directory in your other post), I mean installing the package that provides it, ie. `linux-modules-extra-5.3.0-13-generic`

Comment: @guiverc And how can I do that due installation?

Comment: I don't know what you meant in the last comment.  You're using a machine now to access the internet, you use such a machine to grab what you need; write to thumb-drive or media (I'd use network share) & install from there using `dpkg -i` ; `apt` can install from local too - but you must provide all dependencies or it'll want to go to internet, ie. same limitations as `dpkg`)

Comment: If you want to be leaner, skip Network Manager and go with systemd-networkd and configure with netplan.

Comment: @guiverc I don't understand you, because when I am installing mini.iso, it is not possible to do `dpkg` or `apt` in shell. And without `network access` you can't install even basic kernel. That's why I copied `ko` files. Could you tell me how can I install `mini.iso` and load wifi driver step by step then? Thank you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I strip down Ubuntu?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1807/how-can-i-strip-down-ubuntu)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no need to do what you are doing but Ubuntu Desktop requires 25GB space (recommended) and Ubuntu Server requires 1.5GB space (recommended) so I would start by installing the [server edition](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements).

Next I would install the desktop (not all the apps) onto [the server version](https://itstillworks.com/install-desktop-ubuntu-server-6780086.html):

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop
```

Then reboot and run a script to install your bare minimum GUI requirements.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what [Xubuntu core](https://xubuntu.org/news/introducing-xubuntu-core/) is made for. It consists of Xfce and essential GUI things but does not install all applications provided in the usual Xubuntu desktop.

> Xubuntu core is a slimmed down version of Xubuntu that doesn’t come with all the additional features of a full and modern desktop. We essentially only ship Xfce and the basic look and feel of Xubuntu, so there will be no office suite, media players, et cetera.

Xubuntu core does not have a specialized installer. The recommended way to install it is to download and install the [Minimal ISO](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/MinimalCD) using the *Xubuntu minimal installation* task. Then run (don’t forget the final caret):

```
sudo apt-get install xubuntu-core^
```

Doing only the *Xubuntu minimal installation* task would leave you in the state where WiFi drivers might not be installed, see [Xubuntu 16.04 LTS minimal installation on Alex's blog](http://flux242.blogspot.com/2016/05/xubuntu-1604-lts-minimal-installation.html).